# iOS Bounds Not Updating

Tags: ios, autolayout, segue

I have a container view that embeds a tab bar, and then that tab bar embeds a view—result and setup below. The all views in the tabbar are working except for the last.

I’m not manually setting the frame, although doing that didn’t seem to fix the issue.

The circle shapes in the second-from-top view are constrained via auto-layout with *constrain to margins* turned off, and they work perfectly.

In the picture sent, the elements are constrained with auto-layout *constrain to margins* turned **on**. Turning this off fixes the issue, although that seems like the wrong fix (magic numbers etc).

Rotating the device and then rotating back also fixes the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

When loaded and calling `layoutSubviews`, the views `layoutMargins` are set to respectively

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0)
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

and then after rotating, consistently

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 20.0)
```

I’m literally doing nothing to affect the layout margins.

**EDIT 2:**

The container view was using auto-layout with margins, and custom margins to offset it to be flush with the edge. This was obviously wrong, and changing the layout to exclude the margins fixed the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to try to look for a _difference_ between the setup in the tab children that work and the tab child that doesn't. Could it have anything to do with `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins`?

Comment: Setting that on the view did improve things, in that the text is now visible. But it’s only about 2 pixels from the edge of the screen, so the margins still aren’t being obeyed. With this on, it still will fix itself when rotating the device and then rotating back.